# How to create Dynamic Custom Switch button in Android?

Tags: android, button, dynamic, switch-statement

I am trying to write a code in Android to display 5 Custom Switch button in the layout. I got a code from Internet to develop Custom Switch button. So , i run the code and i got a fancy Switch button in the Layout.

So , now i am trying to display 5 such fancy button from the code , but i don't find any technique to do it.

**Java Code**

```
package com.example.newcustomswitch;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

}}
```

**XML Code**

```
 <ScrollView 
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:mySwitch="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

          <com.example.newcustomswitch.MySwitch
                style="@style/mySwitchStyle"
                android:id="@+id/pickup4"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                mySwitch:pushStyle="true"
                mySwitch:textOnThumb="false"
                mySwitch:thumbExtraMovement="9dp"
                mySwitch:trackTextPadding="1dp"
                mySwitch:thumb="@drawable/stoggle_copy_sm"
                mySwitch:track="@drawable/sgroove_copy_sm"
                mySwitch:textOn="Planned"
                mySwitch:textOff="Un-Planned" 
                mySwitch:leftBackground="@drawable/sleft_background_copy_sm"
                mySwitch:rightBackground="@drawable/sright_background_copy_sm"
                mySwitch:backgroundMask="@drawable/smask_background_copy_sm"
                /> 

 </ScrollView>
```

This is the above static XML code and it display only one switch button in the layout , and i want to display 5 such button from this layout without creating any more child.

Please help me out , suggest me some good solution !!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add more children, either in the XML file itself or programmatically in Java when you are creating the Activity. Sorry, there's no way around that.

ScrollView can only have one child, so you need to use a `LinearLayout` inside the `ScrollView` to host your custom switches.

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">
        <MySwitch />
        <MySwitch />
        <MySwitch />
        <MySwitch />
        <MySwitch />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

If you want to add the views programmatically, you will still need the LinearLayout. Inside your Activity, you can instantiate the views yourself and add them to the LinearLayout like so:

```
// suppose the LinearLayout has android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
MySwitch mySwitch = new MySwitch(this);
linearLayout.addView(mySwitch);
```

You can add many views this way. Use a for-loop if you need to.

Comment: Yes this i know , but i want to do this in dynamic , if i will enter x=5 means then 5 buttons should display , if x=4 then 4 buttons and so on.. please suggest me , how can i do it in dynamic......

Comment: You will still need the LinearLayout. You can always use `new` to instantiate a view. Since you'll probably be doing this in an Activity, you can pass the Activity itself as the Context for the view's constructor (e.g. `new MySwitch(this)`). Obtain a reference to the LinearLayout using `findViewById`, then you can call `linearLayout.addView(...)` to add a view. You can do that X times.

Comment: Yes friend i have tried this , MySwitch mySwitch = new MySwitch(this); but getting error in MySwitch .....

Comment: Then post a stack trace.